# What should be precisely inferred from "as" in the context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> ***As*** the world becomes busier and there're so many more demands on people, I think it might become more difficult for them to relax.

What does ***as*** here in the context refer to ? ***while***, ***because*** or *both* could be inferred?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion. The context is referring to the world which is getting busier, so both might work, but "While" is much better for the meaning.